# An instance variable, which is a pointer to an array item, doesn't point to that item anymore after the object is passed to a class constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a minimal example here where I can reproduce the issue I'm facing.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    long arr[3] = {0x10, 0x20, 0x30};
    long *item1 = &arr[0], *item2 = &arr[1], *item3 = &arr[2];

    A();
};

class B {
public:
    A a;

    B(A);
};

A::A() {}

B::B(A param) {
    a = param;
}

int main() {
    A a = A();
    B b = B(a);

    std::cout << &a.arr[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << a.item1 << std::endl;

    std::cout << &b.a.arr[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << b.a.item1 << std::endl;
}
```

If I pass `a` into the constructor for class `B`, then `a`'s instance variables, which were set to point to the ith element of `arr`, no longer point to that. I *do not* want to pass in a reference of `a` into the constructor for B, I want to pass in a copy as I am currently doing.

### What I expect to happen:

`&a.arr[0]` and `a.item1` have the same value, and `&b.a.arr[0]` and `b.a.item1` have the same value.

### What actually happens:

`&a.arr[0]`, `a.item1`, and `b.a.item1` have the same value, while `&b.a.arr[0]` has a different value.

If I set `item1` to be the memory address of `arr[0]`, then how come `item1` and `arr[0]` don't point to the same thing after passing it in to class `B`? I would expect `&a.arr[0]` to have a different value than `&b.a.arr[0]` of course, but I would also expect `&a.arr[0]` and `a.item1` to have the same value, and `&b.a.arr[0]` and `b.a.item1` to have the same value. Why is this not happening, and how do I make that happen? Again, I don't want to pass a reference to `a` into the constructor for `B`, because I would like to modify `b.a` and return the modified version without affecting the original `a`.

Comment: *What I expect to happen...*  Why do you expect that to happen?  You haven't programmed for that to happen.

Comment: C++ performs so-called _shallow copy_ by default. Your `class A` contains raw pointers. Maybe you should read about [the rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you *copy* an instance of A, you also copy all the pointers.  So the pointers in the new instance all point at the instance copied from, not the the instance containing the pointers.

If you want to pointers in each instance of A to always point at that instance of A, you need to write an explicit copy constructor (and copy assignment, if you want that), that does that.  You may also want a move constructor (and assignment) for different situations, but in this case (as your array elements are just `long`s) it's not particularly useful.

```
A::A(const A &a) {
    std::copy(std::begin(a.arr), std::end(a.arr), std::begin(arr));
    item1 = &arr[0];
    item2 = &arr[1];
    item3 = &arr[2];
}

A &A::operator=(const A &a) {
    std::copy(std::begin(a.arr), std::end(a.arr), std::begin(arr));
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: I added this constructor to my file, but then `b.a.item1` no longer pointed to `b.a.arr[0]`. If I set `*b.a.item1 = 5;`, then `b.a.arr[0]` didn't also change to 5.

Comment: You should be getting a compile-time error with just this constructor, as you assign in B's constructor.  You need to add an assignment operator to make assignment work.